# arch linux warning skipping target

Tags: arch-linux

im installing arch and i have a problem when running

```
pacstrap -i /mnt base base-devel
```

the problem is i get :

```
warning: skipping target: file

warning: skipping target: fileutils

 warning: skipping target: gawk

warning: skipping target: gettext

warning: skipping target: grep

warning: skipping target: gzip

warning: skipping target: pacman

warning: skipping target: sed

warning: skipping target: texinfo

warning: skipping target: util-linux

warning: skipping target: which
```

all i did before running the command is:

used parted to create 2 partitions :

```
(parted) mkpart primary ext4 1MiB 460GiB


(parted) set 1 boot on


(parted) mkpart primary linux-swap 460GiB 476GiB
```

then:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1


mkswap /dev/sda2


swapon /dev/sda2


mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

PS im using MBR/BIOS

please help if you can, and thank you.
also i checked [Problem installing base and base-devel on Arch](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305781/problem-installing-base-and-base-devel-on-arch)

Answer (score 2):

these warnings are for package duplicate, see code and pacman group query

https://git.archlinux.org/pacman.git/tree/src/pacman/sync.c#n526

```
% pacman -Qg base base-devel | grep which 
base which
base-devel which
```